# resource id in xacml for a REST API

Tags: api, rest, xacml, xacml3

If I have an API

https://api.example.org/api/v1/resources

and there is access to a resource with id

[https://api.example.org/api/v1/resources/:id](https://api.example.org/api/v1/resources/%3aid)

How can I write a XACML policy where the resource is an URL with a resource id (the second URL from above)?
How can I put a placeholder/variable there so that I can write a rule for it?

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that you need to write separate policies for various possible id? E.g.

P1 that handles access to resource https://api.example.org/api/v1/resources/:1  and
P2 that handles access to resource https://api.example.org/api/v1/resources/:2 etc.

If so, the idea would be to use an attribute id, say the `resource-id` attribute, to capture the value of the `id` in the URL at the PEP side and pass it to the PDP and to write policies where the target is specified as `string-equals(resource-id,1)` for P1 and `string-equals(resource-id,2)` for P2 etc.

**(edit)**
Based on the clarification, provided, you can do it as follows:

The reasoning in such a case will be similar. You write a Policy that handles all rules for resources and specify its target as `string-equals(resource-type,"resources")` and in that policy specify rules for each resource-id. At the rule level the target would be `string-equals(resource-id,"1")`, `string-equals(resource-id,"2")` etc.

Comment: actually not really, what I need to write is a policy that handles  https://api.example.org/api/v1/resources/ and one that handles  https://api.example.org/api/v1/resources/:id :) I hope I was clear this time :) Thanks for your answer, which might give a clue on how to go about it